# Storing images in a HDF5 file using the C++ API?

Tags: c++, hdf5, imaging

I'm working on a project that needs to be able to store images (among a number of other data sets) in a HDF5 file.

The [C HDF API provides a number of image-specific functions](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/h5image.html) for storing data in a HDF5 file. In particular, images stored using these functions is viewable using the HDFView tool from the HDF group.

However, searching the [C++ API documentation](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/index.html), it seems there is no interface that corresponds to the C version.

Is there any convenient way of writing images to a HDF5 file via C++?

Answer (score 0):

The image-specific functions live in the "high-level" HDF5 interfaces, which only exist for the C and Fortran APIs (aside from the packet table interface for some reason).

You can use the C interface in C++, you'll just need to get the HDF5 ID of the object you want to pass e.g.:

```cpp
H5File file;
auto file_id = file.getId();
H5IMmake_image_8bit(file_id, "Image1", width, height, data);
```